# examples from “Gallery of processor cache effects” and reproducing results

Tags: java, caching, cpu

Reading the following article http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/ 
Which I think it is quite interesting.

I'm trying to follow the examples and reproducing the results from each of the example. In Example 3, they talk about a piece of code and its result that I find not quite clear. 
They mention that for each different sizes of an array the performance which I do understand. But surely the piece of code is not quite complete.

Here is the code

```
int steps = 64 * 1024 * 1024; // Arbitrary number of steps
int lengthMod = arr.Length - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
{
    arr[(i * 16) & lengthMod]++; // (x & lengthMod) is equal to (x % arr.Length)
}
```

But my question, resolves around creating this array of different size. It says in the text :
"We’ll experiment with different array sizes"  While in all examples above it uses the following array:

```
int[] arr = new int[64 * 1024 * 1024];
```

I'm just getting confused with

```
int[] arr = new int[64 * 1024 * 1024];
int steps = 64 * 1024 * 1024;
```

Would I need to change the arr[] and steps or just arr[]?

thanks

Comment: I"m sure the have. Now pretend they're here reading your post right now...how do you think they'll respond to a post that provides no context about what your problem is and no direct query to address? They're going to move on to the next person who needs help. And pick a language. Most answers will differ quite a bit depending on the language.

Comment: What on earth does "do" in this context mean?

Comment: Do not add tags just because the syntax is similar!

Answer (score 0):

So after trying I have the following:

```
        for(int size = 1; size < 40000; size = size * 2){
            //int = 4byte
            //1k = 1024byte or 
            //1000/4 = 256 int as base
            int[] arr = new int[size * 256];
            int steps = 64 * 1024 * 1024 ;
            long lengthMod = arr.length - 1;
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();  
            for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
            {
                arr[(int) ((i * 16) & lengthMod)]++; // (x & lengthMod) is equal to (x % arr.Length)

            }
            long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            double sizekb = ((size * 256) *4)/1024.0;
            System.out.println("Size in byte = "+ sizekb + ", example 3 -- Duration is " + estimatedTime/1000000.d);    
        }
```

The results I get are much slower than the example but does show a similar trend.

Size in kbyte = 1.0, example 3 -- Duration is 75.672

....

Size in kbyte = 32.0, example 3 -- Duration is 61.096
Size in kbyte = 64.0, example 3 -- Duration is 154.679

// A jump between 32kb to 64kb

and another jump between 2MB to 8MB

Size in kbyte = 2048.0, example 3 -- Duration is 219.073

Size in kbyte = 4096.0, example 3 -- Duration is 390.967

Size in kbyte = 8192.0, example 3 -- Duration is 487.781

But overall much slower.(sorry for the sudden extra spaces)